# Adobe PDF Reader quick save on Windows 11 how do I do this?

Tags: windows, adobe-reader

The default behavior where it asks you the folder location then having to replace the file with the same name take too long.

Is there some way to make it faster?

Preference is for something like ctrl-S to save to the file that is open.

Answer (score 1):

The article
[Acrobat / Reader -- Quick Save (FREE)](https://try67.blogspot.com/2019/10/acrobat-reader-quick-save-free.html)
describes a free tool which adds a "Quick Save" menu item to
Adobe's File menu.

This tool is mentioned in the post
[We need a "Quick Save" - Not 5 Clicks](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/we-need-a-quot-quick-save-quot-not-5-clicks/m-p/10695950).
Reading the comments might help if you encounter problems while
installing the tool.